# selenium to get partial screenshots for each of the product elements in a PLP page

Tags: python, image, selenium, python-imaging-library

I have the below working code in the environment Mac OS Python3 Chrome vr (72.0) 64 bit.It only saves one image at a time.

I have xpath that I want to screenshot in a pattern like this:

- //*[@id="products-container"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]
- . . .
- //*[@id="products-container"]/div[1]/div[2]/div[40]

I want to save the screenshot like this

- image1.png
- ...
- image40.png

If anyone can please advice that would be helpful.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
import os
import time
from random import randint
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/Documents/python/Selenium/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get('website-PLP')

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='products-container']/div[1]/div[2]/div[40]") # find part of the page you want image of

location = element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
size = element.size
png = driver.get_screenshot_as_png() # saves screenshot of entire page

im = Image.open(BytesIO(png)) # uses PIL library to open image in memory

left = location['x']
top = location['y']
right = location['x'] + size['width']
bottom = location['y'] + size['height']
im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)).save('image40.png') # defines crop points

sleep(randint(3,3))

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use Loop as follow :**

```
i = 1

while i < 41:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='products-container']/div[1]/div[2]/div["+i+"]") # find part of the page you want image of

    location = element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
    size = element.size
    png = driver.get_screenshot_as_png() # saves screenshot of entire page

    im = Image.open(BytesIO(png)) # uses PIL library to open image in memory

    left = location['x']
    top = location['y']
    right = location['x'] + size['width']
    bottom = location['y'] + size['height']
    im = im.crop((left, top, right, bottom)).save("image"+i+".png")
    i=i+1
```

Comment: Hi Pritam thank you for the help here. I get below error on my screen.
TypeError: must be str, not int. It is pointing at `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='products-container']/div[1]/div[2]/div["+i+"]")`

Comment: Hi Pritam, I did solve it by changing `+i`+ into `str(i)`. Thank you very much for your prompt support here. Very much appreciate it!